# PNP PowerShell in Azure Function fails when to fast triggerd in a time intervall

Tags: powershell, azure, sharepoint, azure-functions

I have an issue with my PNP PowerShell Azure function.

The Azure function will be triggerd by html or logic app and will connect to a SharePoint Site.

After the connection is open, the azure function will set different permissions on this site. But if the azure function is triggerd to fast from two sites the first on will fail with the following error msg.

Set-PnPListPermission : The object is used in the context different from the one associated with the object.

at run.ps1: line 51

- Set-PnPListPermission
- ---

  - CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Set-PnPListPermission], InvalidOperationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.SetListPermission

If there are 20 seconds between the trigger action, the azure function will run successfully.

My first thought was that the reason for this is the instantiate of the azure function...

On local PC the PowerShell script runs smoothly.

Thanks and BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a working solution for me:

1. create a host.json for the azure function with timings like in this example:
   {
           "queues": {
           "maxPollingInterval": 15000,
           "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
           "batchSize": 1,
           "maxDequeueCount": 3,
           "newBatchThreshold": 2
           }
   }
2. set WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT to 1
3. Use CSOM calls instead of PNP. With CSOM you have a higher flexibility...
4. Implement a function to retry the execution with an delay to prevent the SharePoint HTTP error messages
5. If many messages send in short time to sharepoint add additionaly an delay between this step.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a concurrency problem. Ie, you're talking to a service (in this case, SharePoint) that requires clients serialize their access but you have 2 functions running simultaneously accessing it concurrently. (FWIW, you could have the exact same problem if you made 2 calls that tried to update the same table entity).

1. Check sharepoint's options for concurrent access. For example, can your code catch the exception, wait 5 seconds, and retry? In this case, you're doing your own concurrency management.
2. If you're using Durable Functions (in preview), that has some singleton support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-singletons . Even though your function is Powershell, you can still include C# functions that use Durable.

Answer (score 0):

host.json-queues config did not solve this for me. I ended up writing a semaphore workaround instead: look for a record in a storage-table, if its there - delete it, if not - wait till it pops up. Then when done (finally) - write back record.